# Append a 5 dim array to the bottom of a n dim array is Google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two arrays
Ary1 has n columns and length p
its tabular data looks like

[image]

Ary2 has 5 columns and length q
Its tabular data looks like

[image]
I output the data like this

```
  sh.getRange(1, 1, Ary1.length, Ary1[0].length).setValues(Ary1);

  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1, Ary2.length, Ary2[0].length).setValues(Ary2);
```

I want to append an Ary2 under Ary1 to get the result array of length p+q
with tabular data

[image]
So I only have to output the data once

I have tried

```
 var result = Ary1.concat(Ary2);
sh.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);

and

Ary1.push(...Ary2);
sh.getRange(1,1,Ary1.length,Ary1[0].length).setValues(Ary1);

 sh.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

But I get

```
The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 5 but the range has 25.
```

It would be best to mutate Ary1 or Ary2 then to create a new array

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is the difference of the column length of each array. In order to avoid this, it is required to be the same length for each column in the array. So I would like to propose the following modification.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Spreadsheet service is used.

#### Modified script:

```
var Ary1 = ,,,  // Please set the value.
var Ary2 = ,,,  // Please set the value.

if (Ary1[0].length > Ary2[0].length) {
  var len = Ary1[0].length - Ary2[0].length;
  Ary2 = Ary2.map(r => r.concat(Array(len).fill("")));
} else if (Ary1[0].length < Ary2[0].length) {
  var len = Ary2[0].length - Ary1[0].length;
  Ary1 = Ary1.map(r => r.concat(Array(len).fill("")));
}
var values = Ary1.concat(Ary2);
sh.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used. When the Sheets API is used, it is not required to be the same column length in the array.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
var spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set sheet name.
var Ary1 = ,,,  // Please set the value.
var Ary2 = ,,,  // Please set the value.
var values = Ary1.concat(Ary2);
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, spreadsheetId, sheetName, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
```

### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Hello Tanaike, after setting the api and getting the sheet Id I get the error  `The number of columns in the range must be at least 1` when getting  `values`

Comment: @xyz333 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current situation. Because when I tested the sample values, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this?

Comment: I am using your first statement, the loop. This works fine. Thank you!. Can you tell me is this faster, combining the two arrays and outputting them then outputting both arrays separately? Thank you again

Comment: @xyz333 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, I think that when the values are put to Spreadsheet as one array by merging 2 arrays, the cost is lower than that of the method using individually 2 arrays.